# Angular 2 + Auth0 "Cannot read property 'picture' of null" after signing in

Tags: angularjs, authentication, typescript, auth0

I have integrated Auth0 authentication to an Angular 2 application and after signing in, I get this "Cannot read property 'picture' of null" error, BUT if I refresh the page it shows that the user is logged in and the image appears with no errors in the console.

This is the error that I get:
[image]

Link to the github repository:
https://github.com/cstodor/Auth0Lock-Angular2

This is the code of the affected element in `header.component.html`:

```
<span *ngIf="auth.authenticated()">
    <img class="img-circle" width="25" height="25" src="{{ profile.picture }}"> {{ profile.nickname }}
</span>
```

`header.component.ts`:

```
  profile: any;

  constructor(private auth: Auth) {
    this.profile = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('profile'));
  }
```

`auth.service.ts`

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { tokenNotExpired } from 'angular2-jwt';
import { myConfig } from './auth.config';

let Auth0Lock = require('auth0-lock').default;

@Injectable()
export class Auth {
  // Configure Auth0
  lock = new Auth0Lock(myConfig.clientID, myConfig.domain, {});
  profile: any;

  constructor(private router: Router) {
    this.lock.on("authenticated", (authResult: any) => {
      this.lock.getProfile(authResult.idToken, function (error: any, profile: any) {
        if (error) {
          throw new Error(error);
        }
        localStorage.setItem('id_token', authResult.idToken);
        localStorage.setItem('profile', JSON.stringify(profile)); // We will wrap the profile into a JSON object as In local Storage you can only store strings
        console.log('PROFILE: ' + profile);
      });
    });
  }

  public login() {
    // Call the show method to display the widget.
    this.lock.show();
  };
  public authenticated() {
    // Check if there's an unexpired JWT
    // This searches for an item in localStorage with key == 'id_token'
    return tokenNotExpired();
  };

  public logout() {
    // Remove tokens from localStorage
    localStorage.removeItem('id_token');
    localStorage.removeItem('profile');
  };
}
```

Can anyone give me some advice on this issue?

Comment: Shot in the dark since I haven't done much ang2 but `<img [src]="profile.picture"/>` would be my guess. I am thinking using `src` still has issues in ang2 just as it did in ang1

Comment: Are you sure that profile.picture isn't null?  Also, using angular markup like {{ profile.picture }} in a src attribute doesn't work as expected.  You'll want to use ng-src instead.

Comment: @Ronnie Missed... it didn't solve the issue, but good point.

Comment: yeah maybe get rid of the `img` element and just try and output `{{ profile.picture }}` to see if it outputs

Comment: That would output the URL of the avatar image, but still won't appear after login.

Answer (score 1):

`profile` doesn't exist when the ngIf processes, throwing that exception.
Change your ngIf to be `*ngIf="auth.authenticated() && profile"` to delay the processing untill `profile` exists.

I'm guessing youre waiting on a promise to resolve, or maybe you aren't setting `profile` anywhere after you auth, and that's why `profile` is null.

Comment: I've delayed the processing of the avatar image, and the error is not showing in the console anymore, but the image hasn't appeared either. 

Maybe redirecting the user after authentication will solve the issue, but I think that would be a poor workaround.

Comment: @mrTodor, how is the profile being set? Can you include in the question the part of the code that initializes the profile variable?

Comment: @mrTodor, It definitely seems like `profile` is never set. Where are you assigning it? Can you show us the code that runs after authentication?

Comment: Sure, I've uploaded the app into a github repo:
https://github.com/cstodor/Auth0Lock-Angular2

Comment: https://github.com/cstodor/Auth0Lock-Angular2/blob/master/src/app/auth/auth.service.ts#L11
Is this a private key that should be hidden?

Comment: yes it is. but if I remove it, the authentication won't work.

Comment: Ok. On line 24 in auth.service.ts, you need to assign `profile` to `this.profile`. (`this.profile = profile`)

Comment: @AndrewDiamond added `this.profile = profile;` to auth.service.ts:line24. still getting same error.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, we have managed to fix this issue with a help from a friend.
So, the problem was that the `profile` gets the data from `localStorage` when `HeaderComponent` is created, but `localStorage` only has the value when a user is successfully logged in.

For this situation you must subscribe `auth` for profile update and will
get the updated profile from it.

The updated code can be found at the github repository: 
https://github.com/cstodor/Auth0Lock-Angular2